# Why is a class member of type char array suddenly of type const char array in member function?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, initialization, member

I have the following code.

```
#include <exception>

public MyException : public std::exception {
private:
    const char* MESSAGE = "ExceptionReport";

protected:
    static const int MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 200;
    char composedMessage[MyException::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        strcpy(this->composedMessage, this->MESSAGE);
        return this->composedMessage,
    }
};
```

I am wondering why this isn't working. According tu VS 2013 `this->composedMessage` is suddenly `const` when using `strcpy`. I've seen several similar solution to initialize a member of type char array. Why isn't this working for me? What do I not see?

I need `composedMessage` to add some more information via `strcat` in subclasses of `MyException`. But it is no use adding that if it isn't even working in its current form.

Comment: Generally speaking, the idea is not good from design perspective. what() should not modify internal state of the message. What will you do if someone re-throws the exception after evaluating 'what()' on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`what()` is marked `const`.  Since it is `const` you cannot modify the class state(`composedMessage`) in the function.  You can make `composedMessage` `mutable` like:

```
mutable char composedMessage[MyException::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
```

And that will allow you to change it in a `const` function.

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/086de14522e02a2b)</kbd>

Comment: @Lilo I am not sure what you are asking.  If you make `composedMessage` `mutable` then you can modify it in `what` like you have it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Should have recognized the `const` problem of that function. But I haven't encoutered `mutable` yet, so thanks for that! :)